# android opencv camera app hanging

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opencv, freeze

I am creating an android camera app using opencv. First I make it like when I click the start button, it start taking pictures and in every second takes a picture and store it in storage. It works perfectly for me.

Then I tried to make it some tricky by forcing it to take 5 pictures in a second it works well.

But actually I faced problem when I make it to 20 pictures in 1 second. It did not work. The app hangs as soon as I click on the start button. I don't know why. But I think the problem is in threading.

Can someone help me how i will do it.

I have two java files in my project and here is the code.

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial3;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial3View";
    private String mPictureFileName;

    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
    }

    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
        mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture");
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);

            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }
}
```

And the second one is:

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial3;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tutorial3Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private Tutorial3View mOpenCvCameraView;
    private List<Size> mResolutionList;
    private MenuItem[] mEffectMenuItems;
    private SubMenu mColorEffectsMenu;
    private MenuItem[] mResolutionMenuItems;
    private SubMenu mResolutionMenu;
    Thread thread;
    Button start,stop;
    boolean loop=false;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();

                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public Tutorial3Activity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial3_surface_view);
        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2) ;
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loop=true;
                thread = new Thread(new task());
                thread.start();
            }
        });
        stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loop=false;
            }
        });

        mOpenCvCameraView = (Tutorial3View) findViewById(R.id.tutorial3_activity_java_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        List<String> effects = mOpenCvCameraView.getEffectList();

        if (effects == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Color effects are not supported by device!");
            return true;
        }

        mColorEffectsMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Color Effect");
        mEffectMenuItems = new MenuItem[effects.size()];

        int idx = 0;
        ListIterator<String> effectItr = effects.listIterator();
        while(effectItr.hasNext()) {
           String element = effectItr.next();
           mEffectMenuItems[idx] = mColorEffectsMenu.add(1, idx, Menu.NONE, element);
           idx++;
        }

        mResolutionMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Resolution");
        mResolutionList = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList();
        mResolutionMenuItems = new MenuItem[mResolutionList.size()];

        ListIterator<Size> resolutionItr = mResolutionList.listIterator();
        idx = 0;
        while(resolutionItr.hasNext()) {
            Size element = resolutionItr.next();
            mResolutionMenuItems[idx] = mResolutionMenu.add(2, idx, Menu.NONE,
                    Integer.valueOf(element.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(element.height).toString());
            idx++;
         }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);
        if (item.getGroupId() == 1)
        {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setEffect((String) item.getTitle());
            Toast.makeText(this, mOpenCvCameraView.getEffect(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (item.getGroupId() == 2)
        {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Size resolution = mResolutionList.get(id);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(resolution);
            resolution = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolution();
            String caption = Integer.valueOf(resolution.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(resolution.height).toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, caption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    class task implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

            while (loop) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                        "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
                mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Tutorial3Activity.this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


                try {
                    thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Note:** The above code works well for taking 5 pictures in 1 second. But when I change **thread.sleep(200)** to **thread.sleep(50)** for taking 20 pictures in 1 second it hangs.

Comment: Sorry sir it acually hangs, not crashed.

Comment: Still you need logcat ?

Comment: is it getting hand for some particular time like 1 or 2 second.

Comment: It hangs permanently. I have to close the application.